# React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Utilities from './utilities.js';

import Action from './action.jsx';
import SingleGridEl from './singleGridEl.jsx';

class Grid extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.question;
        this.maxN = 110;
        this.array = [];

        this.state = {
            n1: false,
            n2: false,
            n3: false,
            n4: false,
            n5: false,
            n6: false,
            n7: false,
            n8: false,
            n9: false,
            n10: false,
            n11: false,
            n12: false,
            n13: false,
            n14: false,
            n15: false,
            n16: false,
            n17: false,
            n18: false,
            n19: false,
            n20: false,
            n21: false,
            n22: false,
            n23: false,
            n24: false
        }

        this.hideSingleGrid = this.hideSingleGrid.bind(this);
    }

    getRandomQuestion() {   
        let randomN = Utilities.generateRandomNumber(this.array, this.maxN);
        console.log(randomN);
        this.question = this.props.current.data.questions[randomN];
        console.log(this.question);
        return this.question;
    }

    hideSingleGrid(el, val) {
        var s = {};
        s[el] = val;
        this.setState(s);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getRandomQuestion();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="game">
                <div className="grid">

                    <div className="row">
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n1} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n2} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n3} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n4} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n5} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n6} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n7} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n8} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n9} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n10} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n11} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n12} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n13} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n14} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n15} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n16} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n17} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n18} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n19} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n20} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n21} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n22} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n23} />
                        <SingleGridEl visibility={this.state.n24} />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Action t={this.hideSingleGrid} question={this.question} getRandomQuestion={this.getRandomQuestion.bind(this)}/>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

which makes use of a utility method from:

```
var Utilities = (function (array, maxN) {

    function generateRandomNumber(array, maxN) {
        let randomN = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxN) + 1);

        if(array.indexOf(randomN) === -1) {
            array.push(randomN);
        }
        else {
            randomN = generateRandomNumber();
        }

        console.log(array);

        return randomN;
    }

    return {
        generateRandomNumber: generateRandomNumber
    };

})();

export default Utilities;
```

This utility method generates a random number and stores it in an array so that every random number returned is unique based on the max length passed in.

the action.jsx component makes use of the same utility method:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Utilities from './utilities.js';

class Action extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.maxN = 24;
        this.array = [];

        this.state = {
            question: props.question
        }
    }

    getNewQuestion(e) {
        let answerId = "option_" + this.state.question.correct_option;

        if(e.target.getAttribute('data-question') == answerId) {
            let randomNumber = Utilities.generateRandomNumber(this.array, this.maxN);
            this.props.t('n'+randomNumber, true);
            this.setState({
                question: this.props.getRandomQuestion()
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('wrong');
        }
    }

    render() {
        let state = this.state;

        return(
            <div className="action">
                <div className="action-question">
                    <h3>{state.question.question}</h3>
                </div>

                <div className="action-answers">
                    <p data-question="option_1" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_1}</p>
                    <p data-question="option_2" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_2}</p>
                    <p data-question="option_3" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_3}</p>
                    <p data-question="option_4" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_4}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}   

export default Action;
```

when I click on each "p", the "this.getNewQuestion" checks if we clicked on the right answer and move onto the next question with relative answers.

At some point (very randomly) during the game, I get the following error  in the console. The error refers to the utility method:

```
if(array.indexOf(randomN) === -1) {
```

[image]

I can't figure out what's causing that error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that your `array` argument is actually an Array before you call `indexOf` on it:

```
if(Array.isArray(array) && array.indexOf(randomN) === -1) {

}
```

or provide a default argument

```
function generateRandomNumber(array = [], maxN) {
```

This line in your code is calling the function without any arguments and will trigger the error:

```
else {
   randomN = generateRandomNumber();
}
```

Comment: But aren't these already defined as arrays in their respective components?

Comment: Alex, please see my update - calling the function without any arguments is the problem. If you are asking if the `array` reference will point to the parent context's array, then no, a separate array reference is scoped to the `generateRandomNumber` function

Answer (score 0):

I think you called it recursively without any arguments so `array` variable was undefined.

```js
var Utilities = (function (array, maxN) {

    function generateRandomNumber(array, maxN) {
        let randomN = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxN) + 1);
      
        if(array.indexOf(randomN) === -1) {
            array.push(randomN);
        }
        else {
            randomN = generateRandomNumber(array, maxN);
        }


        return randomN;
    }

    return {
        generateRandomNumber: generateRandomNumber
    };

})();
```